# Поле ввода данных формы в виде указания количества звезд

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Хотелось бы узнать идею реализации поля ввода данных в форме в виде указания количества звезд. Где каждая звездочка должна отвечать цифре от 1 до 5

[image: вариант реализации формы]

Comment: А что именно не получается? Было бы не плохо увидеть что наработано, выложи код

Comment: прежде чем задать вопрос лучше всегда погуглить:  
https://codepen.io/daniesy/pen/KkJlF  
https://codepen.io/michaelord/pen/mDfaj  
https://codepen.io/elhoussinelaidi/pen/xErPPJ  
https://codepen.io/MB_K/pen/qNXXaB  
https://codepen.io/raelbr/pen/JaoNgz

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7374/265406

Answer (score 0):

Пример на чистом `CSS/HTML`:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}
form .stars {
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') repeat-x 0 0;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.ie7 form .stars {
  *zoom: 1;
}
form .stars:before,
form .stars:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}
form .stars:after {
  clear: both;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-5:checked ~ span {
  width: 100%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-4:checked ~ span {
  width: 80%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-3:checked ~ span {
  width: 60%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-2:checked ~ span {
  width: 40%;
}
form .stars input[type="radio"].star-1:checked ~ span {
  width: 20%;
}
form .stars label {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0!important;
  text-indent: -999em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  background: transparent!important;
  cursor: pointer;
}
form .stars label:hover ~ span {
  background-position: 0 -30px;
}
form .stars label.star-5:hover ~ span {
  width: 100% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-4:hover ~ span {
  width: 80% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-3:hover ~ span {
  width: 60% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-2:hover ~ span {
  width: 40% !important;
}
form .stars label.star-1:hover ~ span {
  width: 20% !important;
}
form .stars span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 30px;
  background: url('data:image/png;base64,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') repeat-x 0 -60px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-width 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-width 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-width 0.5s;
  -o-transition: -o-width 0.5s;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div class="stars">
  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-1" id="star-1" />
  <label class="star-1" for="star-1">1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-2" id="star-2" />
  <label class="star-2" for="star-2">2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-3" id="star-3" />
  <label class="star-3" for="star-3">3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-4" id="star-4" />
  <label class="star-4" for="star-4">4</label>
  <input type="radio" name="star" class="star-5" id="star-5" />
  <label class="star-5" for="star-5">5</label>
  <span></span>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: А почему Вы не дали ссылку на источник? Если даже и занимаетесь копипастой, то указывайте авторство.